# PHP Benchmarking - inbuilt min() function seems very slow

Tags: php, benchmarking

I have the following test environment for php:

```
class Test {
 public $counter;

 public static $timer = null;
 public static $instances = 0;

 public function __construct() {
    $this->counter++;

    if (self::$instances == 0) {
        self::$timer = microtime(true);
    }

    self::$instances++;
    if (self::$instances % 1000 === 0) {
        echo "Duration of 1000 builds: " . (microtime(true) - self::$timer) . " secs ( " . self::$instances . " )\n";
        self::$timer = microtime(true);
    }
 }

 public function __clone() {
    $this->__construct();
 }
}

$Test = new Test();
$array = array();
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
   $array[$i] = clone $Test;


   for ($z=0; $z<1000; $z++) {
       //$counter = max(0, $i-$z);
       $counter = $i-$z;
       if ($counter < 0) $counter = 0;
       $get = $array[$counter]->counter;
   }
}
```

If I run this script as is, I am getting the following output:

> Duration of 1000 builds: 0.12318682670593 secs ( 1000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.12733101844788 secs ( 2000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.12077212333679 secs ( 3000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.12160491943359 secs ( 4000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.12030696868896 secs ( 5000 )

Yet, if I remove the comments from the line `$counter = max(0, $i-$z);` and instead comment out the next two lines, which identically should do the same thing, I get these results:

> Duration of 1000 builds: 0.3405590057373 secs ( 1000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.33710408210754 secs ( 2000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.3317539691925 secs ( 3000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.34044504165649 secs ( 4000 )
>   Duration of 1000 builds: 0.33882308006287 secs ( 5000 )

Using the built-in php `max` function, takes around 3 times more, then calculating the maximum value manually. Strangely, if I transfer this to a more basic example, without the class cloning, and class construction, the times are equal.

Could any one explain why is php built-in `max` function so much slower here?

Comment: There's overhead for each function call. I'd recommend a third test, where you define a function called `my_max` and then put your other two lines of code in there. You'll probably find it performs the same as using `max` directly.

Comment: @AlexHowansky tried out what you suggested, and you were partly right. But now, my new `my_max` function, underperforms the built-in `max` function. With the `my_max` function I am getting ~0.6 sec / 1000 builds, instead of the ~0.3 sec I am getting with `max`. Can you explain why the difference?

Comment: If you are using >PHP 7 you could prepend max with ```\```, this should give you some boost. If you are not on PHP7 then moving to PHP could give you much more boost.

Comment: I would expect `max()` to be a bit faster than `my_max()` but wasn't expecting it to be twice as fast. Regardless, the difference is irrelevant -- your live code is never going to bottleneck on the `max()` function.

Comment: if you are trying to do it in one line, you can do it without max by including the first assignment in the if condition like this `if ($counter = $i-$z && $counter < 0) $counter = 0;`  I do that stuff in my code all the times just to confuse the junior developers ... lol